# pyodbc encloses result in double quote if field contains 2 single quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

If my result field has 2 single quotes then pyodbc encloses the field in double quotes.  Otherwise the result in enclosed in single quotes.  The double quotes are causing an issue when I try to insert this data into MS SQL Server.

```
('SAM', "O''Brien, Sam", '2016-06-21 14:05')
('JIM', 'Stover, Jim', '2016-06-21 14:05')
```

Is there a parameter for pyodbc to override this default behavior?

Comment: What issues are being caused? That's just how Python represents string literals that contain quotes, I don't think it has anything to do with `pyodbc` specifically.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it is not pyodbc I should be looking at

Comment: *"The double quotes are causing an issue when I try to insert this data into MS SQL Server."* - You shouldn't be using the string representation of the data to perform inserts; you should be using a *parameterized* insert and just passing the data as the parameter values. That way, you don't have to worry about delimiters, locale issues, etc..